# Android debugger hides local variable

Tags: java, android, debugging, undefined-behavior

I have a weird behavior using Android's debugger when executing the following code. The variable *value* disappears just after it has been initialized by the widget. I moved it to to watches but it says `"Cannot find local variable value"`. It does not matter where I place the variable, before the for loop or inside, it behaves the same no matter what. I also printed the variable as you can see in the code and it says `"value is null"` but when I check it by `if (value == null)` it does not stop and finally throws an error when trying to cast it to an integer.

The code:

```
    for (int i=0; i < (view != null ? ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() : 0); i++)
    {
        // Get name of the widget for example field__id,
        // Convert to field name replacing field__id for id
        // or for example field_name to name
        // Check if the field exists in the column name, if so, add the ContentValue
        View widget = ((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(i);
        String widgetName = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(widget.getId());
        String fieldName = widgetName.replace(Model.fieldPrefix,"");
        Object value = null;

        if (columnNames.contains(fieldName)) {
            // TableField on the table matches the field on the form
            try {
                if (widget instanceof TextView) {
                    value = ((TextView) widget).getText().toString();
                } else if (widget instanceof Spinner) {
                    value = ((SpinnerRow) ((Spinner) widget).getSelectedItem()).getId();
                } else if (widget instanceof DatePicker) {
                    String date = AppDatabase.formatDateTime( getContext(), ((DatePicker) widget).getYear() + "-" + ((DatePicker) widget).getMonth() + "-" + ((DatePicker) widget).getDayOfMonth());
                    contentValues.put(fieldName, date ) ;
                } else {
                    throw new ClassCastException("Could not cast the widget"+widget.getClass().toString());
                }
                Log.d(AppController.DEBUG_TAG, "Widget "+widgetName+" value is " + value.toString());

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // Ignore exception:
                value = null;
            }

            TableField tableField = this.getTable().getFieldByName(fieldName);

            if ( (tableField.isPrimaryKey() && (value.equals("-1") || value.equals("")))
                    || !tableField.getNotNull() && value.toString().length()==0  )
                value = null;

            if ( value == null || tableField.getType() == SQLiteCursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) {
                contentValues.putNull(fieldName);
            } else  if (tableField.getType() == SQLiteCursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING || tableField.getType() == SQLiteCursor.FIELD_TYPE_VARCHAR) {
                contentValues.put(fieldName, String.valueOf(value));
            } else if (tableField.getType() == SQLiteCursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER) {
                contentValues.put(fieldName, Integer.valueOf(value.toString()) );
            } else if (tableField.getType() == SQLiteCursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT) {
                contentValues.put(fieldName,Float.valueOf(value.toString()));
            } else if (tableField.getType() == SQLiteCursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB) {
                contentValues.put(fieldName,String.valueOf(value));
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are doing Integer.valueOf(value.toString()) this can easily get you  a NumberFormatException  , what is the error message? Can you also add the Log?

Comment: That is the issue, there is no error, the code follows as normally but the variable disappears from the variables window. I tried changing the class of `value` variable from object to String and now the debugger behaves as expected. Apparently only happens when the variable is an Object.

Comment: Strange behaviour, I just tested this on Eclipse and I could watch my variable...

Comment: It might be a bug from android studio, i am using 0.3.6, latest version nowadays, but i found its quite buggy.

Comment: As of 0.5.8, latest version on May the 14th, 2014, if this is a bug, it is not yet fixed. Works properly on IntelliJ though.

Comment: I'm running Android Studio 0.8.6 and am definitely seeing this issue. If I add ANY local variable to the watches window, I just see "Cannot find local variable 'x'". For instance, in an Activity's / Fragment's onCreate(), the passed in savedInstanceState variable ALWAYS has this problem. Whether it's actually null or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Using version 1.2.2, and this occurs for ALL local variables that are pased in to a method as a parameter.  Talk about a bug!

Answer (score 13):

Do you use proguard with obfuscation?

If yes, that might be the problem - disable it with

```
-dontobfuscate
```

which you should put in your file with proguard rules (usually proguard-rules.txt, check your proguard config in the build.gradle file, like in the example below:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            runProguard true
            zipAlign true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
}
```

Comment: Nope, `testCoverageEnabled true` is the problem here ref: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=123771

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Finally, resolved by removing 'testCoverageEnabled true' from gradle build file.

Comment: Thank you for this. I couldn't figure this one out until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 6):

A similar problem caused by a bug in the gradle `version 1.0.0` which has beed solved in a later `version 1.0.1`

Search your project for `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` which will be found in `build.gradle` files. you may have more than one `build.gradle` file if you are including modules.

whenever you have:

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

Change it to:

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

Then sync gradle. Android Studio will download the new gradle jar file and compiles with it.

Answer (score 4):

Having the same problem here: `Cannot find local variable '[variable_name]'`, and the only difference is that my app is fully debuggable, while the issue occurs with the library code.

I have `minifyEnabled false` for `debug buildTypes` in both **library** and **app** modules.  And during debugging, the `Build Variant` are `debug` for both modules as well.  Even the generated `BuildConfig.java` has the correct value:

`public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");`

**Cause**:

Gradle doesn't propagate build type (debug or release) of application to its dependent library.  It always uses `release` build of library no matter which build type is chosen in application (the library dependency is specified as `compile project(':library')` in the app's build.gradle).

**Solution**:

`build.gradle` in **library** module

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        defaultPublishConfig 'release'
        publishNonDefault true
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` in **app** module

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: "release")
}
```

instead of doing:

```
compile project(':library')
```

[image: issue screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If your build uses the [jack toolchain](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html) this can be the source of the problem. In my case, disabling jack solves the problem:

```
buildTypes {
...
    debug {
        jackOptions {
            enabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Note: 1.8 source compatibility requires jack!

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. It was version mismatch between Kotlin used in Android Studio and the one declared in app-level `build.gradle` file (probably after Android Studio update). Bumping the version in `build.gradle` helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
Android studio cannot show local variable data when used with Proguard.

**Following settings need to be used during debugging:**

1.

Either add -donotobfuscate property under proguard-rules.pro file,
-dontobfuscate
OR

2.

Under debug buildtypes inside build.grade, 
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false

Latter option is more recommended as ur production apk many need to be compressed.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

uh...  In my case，I just rebuild project to fix it！